# Validate one field when another model changes

Tags: angularjs

There are a number of questions that already exist that discuss being able to validate one field based on the value of another model changing. Many of these questions seem out of date as the changes that have happened in Angular post-date these questions.

I have one directive that allows a user to choose a "color". There are other directives that allows a user to choose "sizes" (width and height). Some colors are only available in certain sizes.

My "color" directive has an additional directive assigned that manages validation. If the width and height are over a certain amount, I add my error message and everything is great.

However, this same validation will not trigger when the "sizes" change. I have tried to use `on-change="form.myfield.$validate()` on the size fields and this provides the desired functionality, but then because the field becomes invalid, the "color" model is now `undefined`.

**Is there a simple way to trigger validation on a field when the value of another model is changed?**

Here is a Plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DQhRFcIKkLlf0NfnuDJa?p=preview

---

EDIT

The more I think about this, the more I believe I realize that validation on this type of application is going to be incredibly difficult due to the complex interactions that take place between various multi-element directives. I think it might be simpler to just set the acceptable values for various inputs based on certain model values, thus preventing any invalid values from being chosen in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by adding a watch on `width` and `height` properties and setting the validity of the color input conditionally.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {
      description: 'Red',
      sku: '5555',
      oversize: true
    },
    {
      description: 'Blue',
      sku: '6666',
      oversize: false
    }
  ]
  
});


app.directive('oversize', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      function validator (modelVal, viewVal) {
        var w = scope.width;
        var h = scope.height;
        var isValid = false;
        if (w > 4 && h > 4) {
          if (modelVal.oversize === true) {
            isValid = true;
          }
        } else {
          isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
      
      }
      ctrl.$validators.oversize = validator;
      scope.$watch('width', function () {
        ctrl.$setValidity("oversize", validator(scope.color));
      })
      scope.$watch('height', function () {
        ctrl.$setValidity("oversize", validator(scope.color));
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form action="" name="form">
      
      <p>Red is available in oversize, blue is not.</p>
      <p>If both width and height are > 4, blue cannot be used</p>
      
      <div ng-show="form.color.$error.oversize">That is not available in this size</div>
      
      Color
      <select oversize name="color" ng-model="$parent.color" ng-options="c.description for c in colors track by c.sku"></select>
      
      <br>
      
      Width
      <select name="width" ng-model="width" ng-options="v for v in [1,2,3,4,5]"></select>
      <br>
      
      Height
      <select name="height" ng-model="height" ng-options="v for v in [1,2,3,4,5]" id=""></select>    
    </form>
    
    <p>Oversize for {{color.description}} is {{color.oversize}}</p>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you then resolve the color model being undefined when the selection is invalid? This example has the same effect as I was running into before, using `$validate()` in a `$watch` was giving me the same results as this -- The color model is still undefined so how do I present useful error information to the user if I can't tell them where the error is?

Comment: I dont see color model undefined when the selection is invalid. Or may be I am not understanding you correctly.

Comment: `{{color}}` outputs nothing here and other areas of my application throw console errors that my model is undefined.

Comment: But I see `{{color.description}}` getting printed correctly in my code snippet.

Comment: Run the snippet and select width=5, height=5, then lastly select Blue. If 5x5 is selected and the color is changed, it does not validate correctly.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I believe I realize that validation on this type of application is going to be incredibly difficult due to the complex interactions that take place between various multi-element directives. I think it might be simpler to just set the acceptable values for various inputs based on certain model values.